# If $e^{f(z)}$ is constant can we say that $f(z)$ is constant?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

A quick question. If $e^{f(z)}$ is constant can we say that $f(z)$ is constant? ($z \in \mathbb{C}$). Can this be said directly without giving any proof or maybe stating a theorem? Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You can say if if you assume f is continuous. Otherwise it's false.

Comment: Thanks is it something that I have to prove or is it kind of obvious? This is part of a question I came across

Comment: Assume $f$ is continuous, and apply a branch of $\log$ to both sides of $e^{f(z)}=c$. What do you get?

Answer (score 6):

\begin{align*}
f(z) = \left \{ \begin{array}{cc} 0 \quad & \vert z \vert \leq 1 \\
2 \pi \mathrm{i} \quad & \vert z \vert > 1 \end{array} \right.
\end{align*}